# does the 'double arrow' => really mean 'implies'?

Tags: z3, smt

Does

```
(=> (f g))
```

always mean the same thing as

```
(or (not f) g))
```

?

The two expressions behave differently in my model. While using *=>* gives me *UNSAT*, using the other variant does not yield any result (*timeout*). I would be content just having a list of operators and their meanings. I am aware of the SMTLIB standard, but the documents don't explicitly talk about the meanings of operators. Specifically '*=>*' seems to double as an alias for the '*ite*' (if_then_else) operator if used in a ternary expression and I'm quite confused about that.

I set the *AUFLIA* logic, if that's relevant.

I'm looking for a simple yes or no answer first. And a proper documentation about SMT2 (maybe a book) second.

I have [this](https://gist.github.com/3175462) rather large model generated from Daniel Jackson's marksweep model for alloy4 of those of you who are willing to see for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expressions are incorrect/unwellformed.

`=>` indeed means 'implies'. In other words, `(=> f g)` is equivalent to `(or (not f) g)`.

If in doubt, you could prove it using Z3. [The below query](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/kZtE) is `unsat`:

```
(declare-const p Bool)
(declare-const q Bool)

(define-fun conjecture () Bool
    (= (=> p q) 
       (or (not p) q)))

(assert (not conjecture))
(check-sat)
```

Comment: Thanks. It was indeed malformed.